# How can I decode an http string name

Tags: http, utf-8, decode

I am trying to decode filenames in HTTP but the string from browser messages are different.

In my test file I put the name **ç.jpg**.

What I need is the name **%C3%A7.jpg**.

But the browser is sending **%C3%83%C2%A7.jpg**.

It's not UTF8, UTF16 or UTF32.

For another example I test the file name **€.jpg**.

What I need is the name **%E2%82%AC.jpg**.

But I am receiving **%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC.jpg**.

how can I convert this names to UTF8?

Comment: Any idea how those filenames are generated? It definitely appears that there's a bug in creating those urlencoded filenames. Also, what language are you trying to solve this in?

Comment: Hi.
I am trying to make an http server in C++.
When I receive the get file message, this was the filename sending by chromium browser. I test with firefox and I have the same file name.
I think it's a new http encoder but I didn't find anything about this.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I played with this for about 30 minutes and I finally figured it out.

This is how the original string was encoded:

1. The string was in UTF-8
2. Some encoding mechanism *thought* it was CP1252, and based on that wrong assumption re-encoded it to UTF-8 again.
3. The resulting string was url-encoded.

To get back to a real UTF-8 string, this is what I did. (note, I used PHP, don't know what you are using but it should be doable in other languages just the same).

```php
$input = '%C3%A2%E2%80%9A%C2%AC %C3%83%C2%A7';

$str1 = urldecode($input);

echo iconv('UTF-8', 'CP1252', $str1);
// output "€ ç"
```

So that conversion is counter intuitive. We're converting *to* CP1252, but still end up with a UTF-8 string. This only works because an existing UTF-8 was falsely treated as CP1252, and that incorrect interpretation was *then* converted to UTF-8. So I'm just reversing this double-encoding.

In other languages there might be a few more steps, this works in just 1 line with PHP because strings are bytes, not characters.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

I will try to find a tutorial to decode this CP1252 to utf8.

I am using C++ in linux.

Comment: @user1806656 you probably also have an iconv function then ;). Note that you have to convert UTF-8 to CP1252, not the opposite! It's weird but it's what this is.